# Passing an array from a page template to another php file in theme folder in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a front-page.php template which lists the 5 latest posts along with some custom post types in between. When one clicks on the more button at the bottom it needs to ajax load more posts.

So I created a loop-home.php file according to [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress--wp-23232)
I couldn't use this code by default because I have a nested loop on the first load of homepage and this script messes it up.

So I wrote a new query to ajax OLDER posts only. I collected the post ids of the posts already present when the page loads and stored it in an array.

I now need to use this array in the query of loop-home.php
I am using this method because offset does not work with pagination and I need to pass these IDs to post__not_in parameter in the query.

**Method 1:**
I tried (in loop-home.php)

```
$exempt = $_REQUEST['exemptArray'];
```

But it returns NULL.

**Method 2:**(Using Ajax)

I tried (in front-page.php)-

```
<script>
var exemptArray = '<?php echo json_encode($exemptions); ?>';
</script>
```

Then I went to script.js and added-
    //create json object from the var array

```
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(exemptArray);

var dataToPost = { 'jsonArray':jsonArray };

//send POST data to PHP and handle response
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: loopHome, //stored path in variable. working.
  data: dataToPost,
  success: function (data) {

    console.log('I have already sent it.'); //I am getting this log. Working.

  }
});
```

Then in loop-home.php-

```
$exempt = json_decode($_POST['jsonArray']);
```

Still getting NULL on var_dump($exempt)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you run loop-home.php seperate it will pop null cause you are not posting any data to it.

Comment: @Tyranicangel I don't understand what you are saying...

Comment: The javascript posts to the loop-home.php.So try console.log(data) and give a var_dump($exempt) in loop-home.php.

Comment: While collecting those values instead of saving into variable, why dont you try to save into the sessions which is very easy to access for later purposes.

Comment: Have you tried globalising the array? `global $array`

Comment: @Tyranicangel: I did console.log(data) in the success of the ajax and the strangest thing happens- it is outputting entire html of the posts I want to exempt instead of giving me just an array of the ids! How does one explain this?

Comment: @Tyranicangel console.log of dataPost gives me [object object]. something fishy here?

Comment: @krishna never done that before. can you please link me to a resource?

Comment: @henrywright going to try globalising array. just a quick question don't i have to include front-page.php in loop-home.php for this to work?

Comment: @henrywright I declared global $exemptions in header.php, declared it as array in front-page.php like this: $exemptions = array();, did an array push and collected all the post ids and then called it in loop-home var_dump($exemptions); I am still getting NULL. :(

Comment: console.log is giving you object meaning you are returning an array add dataType:'JSON' into your ajax.Moreover while sending data to the php page there is no need to json stringify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'foo.php',
    data:{myArr:exemptArray},
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

Your php page:

```
$input=$_POST['myArr'];
$exempt=json_encode($input);
```

In your console you will get an array. [object object] is a reference to an associative array.So in the above code result is same as exemptArray.Try something like this you will be able to.I could not find your array composition anywhere so i used exemtarray itself.

Comment: I think we are getting really close-
Here's what I did and what I am getting-
http://pastebin.com/y1UCjB8v
So POST is not happening?

Comment: I tried manually entering the post ids in the query array just to see the var dump of $exempt=json_encode($input); I am getting string(4) "null" Does that make any sense to you...?

Comment: If it helps my array is [81,69,42,34]
Not an associative array right?

Comment: You can send and receive any array.It is not just limited to associative.I have added error function into ajax.If dataType is JSON you should not get a string in console.log.

Comment: If possible can you show your php page you are posting to

Comment: here's a link to the php page I am posting to- http://pastebin.com/VHs967Da
here's a link to the ajax that fetches the html of this page and sets the next page number- http://pastebin.com/BEiZMjym

Comment: I just var_dumped the query and found that it is returning null which means the array is getting passed and it is working! However when I click the more button it loads posts (duplicates). I realize it is out of the scope of this question. But do you see something fishy in my loop-home.php?

Comment: First thing never generate the total html code on the server end.Use your php page to just query the database and send response back in form of JSON objects.Use your front end javascript/jquery or whatever to display the data onto your html.And in your case I would strongly suggest using "Angularjs" for front end.If you dont want to use angular just your your existing jquery.In your ajax you did post post the exempt array to the php page.Only the get variables are assigned.So the server is responding with the same data twice.